# Computing fundamental group of the complement to three infinite straight lines, and of complement to $S^1 \cup {Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

**Question 1:** Find the Fundamental group of the *complement* to three infinite straight lines that have no common points in $\mathbb{R^3}$

[[image: 3 lines in <span class=]$\mathbb{R^3}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk506.png)

**Question 2** Compute the fundamental group of the *complement* of $S^1 \cup Z \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ where $S^1$ is the unit circle in the $xy$ plane and $Z$ is the vertical axis, see picture.

[image: Circle line]

I know that the fundamental group of $(X, x_0)$ denoted $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is the set of homotopy classes of loops in $(X, x_0)$. If $\lambda$ is a loop in $(X, x_0)$, we write $[\lambda]$ for the homotopy class $\lambda$ that is:

$[\lambda]=\{\mu | \lambda \simeq \mu \}$

$\lambda$ and $\mu$ are homotopic in $ (X, x_0)$ if there is a map $H$ such that:

$H:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ satisfying:

- $H(s,0)=\lambda(s) \forall s \in I$
- $H(s,1)=\mu(s) \forall s \in I$
- $H(0,t)=H(1,t)=x_0 \forall t \in I$

---

I think van Kampen's theorem could be used in question 2, as we are dealing with union of two space. The theorem says $(X, x_0)$ a pointed space, $X= A \cup B$ where $A \cap B$ is path connected and contains the base point $x_0$. Then: $\pi_1(X, x_0)=\pi_1(A, x_0) *_{\pi_1(A \cap B, X_0)} \pi_1(B, x_0)$. But the problem is we are dealingn with the complement of the union. How would this change things?

Many thanks for your help, I am really struggling with these types of questions

Comment: I think it shouldn't be too hard to prove that $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus three lines is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus three points.

Comment: is that $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of integers or the $z$-axis?

Comment: The second one is homotopically equivalent to the torus, so its fundamental group is $\Bbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @thinker I took the liberty to substitute "$S^1\cup\Bbb Z$" with "$S^1\cup Z$" because, $\Bbb Z$ is usually dedicated only to the set of integer numbers.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solutions. I am having a lot of trouble 'getting there' .. applying theorems etc. I will have a second look

Comment: Second one deformation retract to a torus and hence it is homotopy equivalent to a torus.

Comment: @HarshCurious Do you mean the line and circle is homotopic to the torus, or its complement is?

Comment: @thinker The complement!

Comment: @HarshCurious thanks. Can I ask how you knew this? Was it from an intuitive sense or did you use explicit calculations?

Comment: @thinker Well actually it was intuitive. Let me explain how though. Just think about a torus, made out of a sheet if you will. Now increase the thickness of the sheet. Go on doing this and you will see that what your left with is precisely a line and a circle.